# Multiple Grid in Crystal Reports in Group Head

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I want to have the following result out of my data:

> ```
> Header 1      Header 3    Foo 11
> Car 1         Foo 1       Foo 12
> Car 2         Foo 2   
> Car 3         Foo 3       Header 4
> Car 4         Foo 4       Bar 1
> Car 5         Foo 5       Bar 2
>               Foo 6       Bar 3
> Header 2      Foo 7       Bar 4
> House 1       Foo 8       Bar 5
> House 2       Foo 9
> House 3       Foo 10
> ```

I cannot do it in details section with the `Format with multiple columns` because I need to group some values for the group headers.

Is it possible to get the result above? With breaks to the next column as you can see in the group with the "foo" and not break to the next site.

I am using Crystal Reports 11.5 and I tried it with subreports (they allow no break column).

**Solution**:

As Chris said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668940/1743593), I tried it with "Format Groups with multiple columns" in the Details area and I removed the duplicates with the following formula in "surpress" in details area:

```
if({#counter} = 1) then
false
else
{@var}=previous({@var})
```

where counter is a counter for the type I want to display, in my case it were ids of people. The counter is needed to display the first dataset, otherwise it is surpressed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "Format Groups with multiple columns"?

It's an option visible in the Layout tab of the Section Expert after you select "Format with multiple columns" on the details section.  See [this documentation](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-34205) and look at the image about halfway down the page to see it in the dialog.